# Need Regex Help (preg_match_all)

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

This is my image

```
<img src="" data-original="'.$this->url.'/img/image'.$row['id'].'.jpg" id="song-art'.$row['id'].'"  alt="'.$row['title'].'" class="animated fadeIn load-delay">
```

In PHP I need to get the content of `data-original`, so I tried:

```
preg_match_all('/<img data-original="([\d\D]*)" id="song-art'.$_GET['id'].'".*">/iU', $track[0], $art);
```

I'm not very good with regex, why it doesn't work?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML, use a DOM parsing library.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, can I see this solution as answer?

Comment: It's too complex for me to write as an answer, especially since I don't know your whole document layout. Read up on how to use `DOMDocument` and try to do it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should match everything inside the double quotes that it is not a double quote.

```
data-original=\"([^\"]*)\"
```

EDIT:
To select the data-original of certain artist with id XXXX.

```
data-original=\"([^\"]*)\".*id=\"song-artXXXX\"
```

so in php it should be like:

```
$id_artist= 'XXXX';
preg_match_all('data-original=\"([^\"]*)\".*id=\"song-art'.$id_artist.'\"', ....);
```

replace XXXX with the id of the artist you want to look for, and add the other params to the function.

Comment: I tried this, but still doesn't work `preg_match_all('/<img data-original=\"([^\"]*)\" id="song-art'.$_GET['id'].'".*">/iU', $track[0], $art);`

Comment: I do not think you are using reg_match_all() correctly...why do you add this: id="song-art'.$_GET['id'].'".*">/iU to the pattern ?

Comment: I'm using that to select the right image (there are different song-art in the same page)

Comment: OK, so you want to select the current data-original of certain artist. I will edit for improving the regex, with the new info.

Comment: I tried this `preg_match_all('data-original=\"([^\"]*)\".*id=\"song-art'.$_GET['id'].'".*">/iU', $track[0], $art);` then I tried `$TMPL['open_graph_twt'] = '<meta name="twitter:image" content="'.$art[1][0].'">';` but again it's not working